# Javascript check if url exists and check some information displayed on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, html

I would like to know if there exist any way to check if a url exists and to check information on it.

Here you have an example about what I mean:

- imagine you are in "https://de.yahoo.com/?p=us" webpage.
- Then using Javascript check if "https://www.google.com" exists and if it contains both words "google" and "yahoo"

  - if it exists:

    - Check if the word "google" is in the page:

      - if it exists return "true"
      - if it doesn't return "false"
    - Check if the word "yahoo" is in the page:

      - if it exists return "true"
      - if it doesn't return "false"
  - if it doesn't exist:

    - return "false"

Comment: The page you check will need to have CORS enabled which is not likely, so the only option is to create proxy script that will fetch 3rd party page and return the result.

Comment: Do you recommend me any tutorials or any examples doing what you purpose? Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to search how to get the page using server side script of your choice. If it's php then you can use curl or file_get_contents function.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this. In the meantime other proposals are accepted also

Answer (score 1):

Writing a full code solution for you in this answer may not be possible for me, But I will set a pathway for you. By following it you can get the desired result.

First of all, getting contents of a webpage which is not under your domain nor in your control will be not possible through javaScript as browser will prevent it unless CORS is enabled on that domain.

To overcome this shortage, you need to get the contents of the page through a server side scripting, most probably you will use php. So create a file on your server to which you will make ajax request with the desired url as data. In jquery you can achieve this as follow:

```
    $.ajax('getPage.php', {
        data: 'url=your desired url' 
    }).success(function (data) {
        //Process the data
    }).error(function () {
       //Error Handler
    });
```

Now in php file, use curl or get_file_contents function to get the data from the page

You can do something like this in getPage.php

```
    $page = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
echo $page;
```

Now you can either use the JavaScript and parse the contents received via ajax and check for your keyword or you can do the parsing right in your getPage.php file and return either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the same domain, subdomain, port, or protocol, you can set a JSON response to you AJAX request and lets say that the response will contain all of the required info with the keys: `"checkResults"` the Ajax would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "YourURL",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (data.checkResults) {
               //do whatever
           }
       });
```

this can't be done on a different domain, sub-domain, port, or protocol. unless ofc the CORS is enabled which is not likely the case.

**Notes**

> Due to browser security restrictions, most Ajax requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, port, or protocol. Script and
>   JSONP requests are not subject to the same origin policy restrictions.

SEE: [Breaking-cross-domain](http://www.slideshare.net/SlexAxton/breaking-the-cross-domain-barrier) it is really helpful

Plugins for cross-domain [cross-domain-plugin](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery--net-10225)

---

CORS Anywhere
CORS Anywhere is a node.js proxy which adds CORS headers to the proxied request.
To use the API, just prefix the URL with the API URL. (Supports https: see `[github repository][3]`)

If you want to automatically enable cross-domain requests when needed, use the following snippet:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
    'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing',
    function (response) {
        console.log("> ", response);
        $("#viewer").html(response);
});
```

credit: @jherax